# merge two dataframes of different lengths but keep additional column values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two dataframes of different lengths, which should match on all 35 columns except for the extra two columns the second dataset has, which provides an additional and much-needed value. So in this example LR_06_18_PPD is much longer and has 35 columns, where as LR_06_18_COU_D is much shorter and has 37 columns (the first 35 being the same name as the other dataset). The extra two columns in the second dataset (Change Indicator and Date) have a flag ("D") and a date in them, respectively. When I try to merge them using:

```
LR_06_18_COU_deleted = LR_06_18_PPD.merge(LR_06_18_COU_D,how='left')
```

I get a dataset the length of the first dataset, which is what I want as the other dataset should be matched to the other (the second dataset should match corresponding rows in the first dataset but have in addition the Change Indicator and Date columns), however while the length is now 37 columns and Change Indicator and Date are included, the flags and dates themselves have completely vanished. The matched rows should all have "D" in the Change Indicator column, but they do not, there are no "D" flags in the merged dataset. Does anyone know how to do this but keep the values in the added columns from the second dataset?

Edit:

First five rows of first dataframe (for the last few columns):
Proprietor (4)|Date Proprietor Added|Additional Proprietor
    nan        15-11-1995             Y
    nan        09-03-2017             N
    nan        26-07-2006             N
    nan        30-05-2007             N
    nan        09-02-2017             N
    nan        01-08-2007             N

First five rows of second dataframe (for the last few columns):
Additional Proprietor indicated| Change Indicator| Change Date
N                                D                 01-06-2018
N                                D                 01-06-2018
N                                D                 01-06-2018
N                                D                 01-06-2018
N                                D                 01-06-2018
N                                D                 01-06-2018

Desired output:
Proprietor (4)|Date Proprietor Added|Additional Proprietor| Change Indicator
    nan        15-11-1995             Y                     D
    nan        09-03-2017             N                     D
    nan        26-07-2006             N                     D
    nan        30-05-2007             N                     D
    nan        09-02-2017             N                     D
    nan        01-08-2007             N                     D

(can't fit date column to the right).

I might even be asking the wrong question. What I'm actually trying to do is delete every row in the first dataset (LR_06_18_PPD) for which another dataset (LR_06_18_COU_PPD - LR_06_17_COU_D is the subset of this where Change Indicator == "D") meets multiple conditions (matches on 'Title Number' and 'Postcode' columns, and 'Change Indicator' == "D". I don't know if this can be done without first merging the datasets. I initially tried for and if loops such as :

```
for rows in LR_06_18_PPD:
    if LR_06_18_PPD['Title Number'] == LR_06_18_COU_PPD['Title Number'] and 
    LR_06_18_COU_PPD['Change Indicator'] == "D":
        del rows
```

but that gives me:
raise ValueError(msg)

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

So I am trying to merge the datasets before deleting the rows where the Change Indicator column is equal to D. If anyone can shed any light on the best way to do this that would be brilliant. I also want to then append the rows where Change Indicator is equal to A.

Comment: My imagination is not great. "Show me", not "tell me".

Comment: Kat, your problem is probably easy to solve. However, you need to provide some data. Could you post (in text format) five rows of each data frame. Picking, just a few columns that are sufficient to exemplify and solve the problem would be fine. It will also help if you post the desired output of the merge.

Comment: Have edited above. I also checked the datatypes of both datasets and some were different so I have changed them so they are all the same for the matching 35 columns, however merging still leaves the last two columns I need blank/ "nan"